# Допускается ли в официальных документах пропускать слово "для"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подчинённые приносят на проверку технические документы, в которых часто пропускают слово "для", например:

- цех окончательной сборки изделия - в смысле цех "для" окончательной сборки изделия;
- штуцер заправки - в смысле штуцер "для системы" заправки;
- заглушка испытания - в смысле заглушка "для" испытания;
- колесо выбора режима работы - в смысле колесо "для" выбора режима работы.
  Подскажите, допустимо ли в официальных документах пропускать слово "для"?

Comment: В деловом стиле должно быть "изделий", не одно изделие же собирают.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь я вижу **не официальный или нейтральный** стиль, а только **технический**, в котором закреплена определенная терминология.

Поэтому подобные наименования должны быть **технически грамотными**. В данном случае это **конкуренция** предложного и беспредложного родительного падежа.

При беспредложном управлении на первом месте значения **определения**, а при наличии предлога ДЛЯ — значение **предназначенности**.

**Я бы записала так**:

1. *Цех окончательной сборки изделия* (= сборочный цех).
2. *Штуцер заправки* (= заправочный штуцер).
3. *Заглушка для испытания*.
4. *Колесо выбора режима работы / для выбора режима работы* (равноправные варианты).

Но нужно использовать **всегда один** (выбранный) вариант.

Comment: Первое не звучит. Там нужно указать предназначенность. Без "изделия" звучит нормально (обычно предмет не вносят в название цеха). В четвёртом лучше без предлога, потому что само слово нуждается в определении.

Comment: Возможно, это уже специалисты разберутся. Пункт. 1. Изделия бывают очень сложные – может, для одного изделия требуется отдельный цех. Пункт 4.  Возможно, лучше без предлога.

Comment: Пусть так, но тогда всё равно делают одинаковые изделия, а не одно изделие. Единственное — разговорный ваиант.

Answer (score 0):

На предприятиях и учреждениях, и даже у ИП, имеются утверждённые структуры и штатные расписания с наименованиями подразделений.

*Допустимо ли в официальных документах пропускать слово?*

В официальных документах пропускать или изменять названия подразделений не допускается.

Answer (score 0):

В современном языке слово цех употребляется чаще всего в значении – элемент (единица) производственной структуры промышленного предприятия.
«Производственная структура - состав цехов и служб пред¬приятия с указанием связей между ними». ГОСТ 14.004-83
Все цеха предприятия подразделяются на категории в зависимости от типа производственного процесса https://www.profiz.ru/peo/4_2017/struktura_predprijatija/
Как результат, названием цеха  становится наименование вида производственного процесса (!), осуществляемого цехом.
Например, предлогу «для» нет места в сочетании: процесс (процедура, операция) окончательной сборки. Соответственно, этот предлог стал лишним в наименовании: цех (участок, конвейер, линия) подготовки производства, окончательной сборки.
Вполне допустим вариант написания с изменением порядка слов: литейный цех, кузнечно - прессовый цех, сборочный цех.
Сочетание «цех для», в смысле «для кого / для чего предназначен», встречается (в КРЯ) нечасто.
Это был турбинный цех для фирмы AEG. [Владислав Быков, Ольга Деркач. Книга века (2000)]
Успели построить только редакционно-издательский корпус и цех для печати газет. [В соперничестве с «гаражными» типографиями // «Витрина читающей России», 2002.08.02]
Из этих цитат становится ясным, что в тексте официального документа сочетание «цех для» будет ошибкой.

Что касается "штуцера", "заглушки" и "колеса", то упоминание в официальном документе этих терминов должно всегда строго соответствовать их написанию в стандартах и прочей соответствующей НТД. Видоизменения терминов (хотя бы только добавлением предлога «для») в этом случае будут недопустимы.

Comment: Термины абстрактны.

Comment: Абстрактные и конкретные термины. Абстрактные термины – это такие термины, которые служат для обозначения качеств или свойств, состояний, действия вещей. Они обозначают качества, которые рассматриваются сами по себе, без вещей…, а потому и без определённого пространства и времени. Примером абстрактных терминов могут служить такие термины, как «тяжесть», «объём», «форма», «цвет», «интенсивность», «твёрдость», «приятность», «вес», «гуманность»...  
Учебник логики. Георгий Челпанов.   https://azbyka.ru/otechnik/Spravochniki/uchebnik-logiki-chelpanov/2

Comment: Там не зря заменено на "понятие". *Термин "камень"* — это же бред. Не употребляют так это слово. В логике другое, оно отличается от реального употребления. Вот если бы в словаре такой пример нашли... А там такого быть не может.

Comment: Оно противоречит словарному определению: *Слово или словосочетание, являющееся названием определённого понятия какой-нибудь специальной области науки.* Научным из тех примеров можно считать лишь "квадрат", и то он слишком прост, чтобы называть его термином (стилистика). Термины — это слова, которые не являются общеизвестными и простыми.